# Add new field to every JUL log statement

Tags: java, java.util.logging

Right now I have an application that writes logs using the standard java.util.logging package and SimpleFormatter. I'd like to know if there's a way to add some sort of "context" field to **every** log statement.

What I'd like is something like this. Let's say I have a Tetris game, that has been logging moves, and I'd like it to write the current score on every log statement:

```
package org.tester;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Tetris implements HighScoreGame {
    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("org.tester.Tetris");
    int score;

    void horizontalMove(Move move) {
        logger.info("Going sideways: " + move.direction);
        moveTarget();
    }

    void verticalMove() {
        logger.info("Falling...");
        if(landed()) {
          updateScore();
          logger.info("Done falling");
        } else {
          logger.info("Falling again in 5s")
        }
    }
}
```

I could just append the field to the message.

```
logger.info("Score:" + score + " Falling...");
```

I don't want to because I would have to go through and edit every log statement, and the real application is fairly big. It would also prevent me from configuring the log entry with the Formatter.

I guess I could extend SimpleFormatter and Logger, but it seems like something like that should already exist.

I also realize that it's possible that JUL is just too primitive to do what I want, so switching to another logging framework like Log4j2 might be the right solution. Log4j in particular has [Mapped Diagnostic Contexts](http://www.baeldung.com/mdc-in-log4j-2-logback), which might be what I need except that it's per-thread rather than per-logger.

What's the best approach here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JDK logging is setup to just include everything you need as a log parameter.  However, there are some tricks you can do but you have to decide where you want to place this context.

If you just want the rendered output to show the score then subclass SimpleFormatter and override the `format` method to prepend the score.  As long as your subclass has reference to the `Tetris` object your custom formatter will produce the output.  This method is preferred but you won't be able to inspect this at the time of filtering.

Another option would be to create a custom [filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/logging/Filter.html) that [modifies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogRecord.html#setMessage-java.lang.String-) the [current message](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogRecord.html#getMessage--) by prepending the score and returning `true`.  Then install the filter on the [handler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/logging/Handler.html#setFilter-java.util.logging.Filter-) in use or install it on [every logger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html) that is generating log records.  One issue here is that you should detect if the LogRecord has already been altered to ensure you are not repeatedly altering the message.